# VS2019 Oracle connection not working in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2019, attunity

I have installed the Professional version of Visual Studio 2019 and I am unable to connect to Oracle DB Source using the Microsoft connector. I am getting the below error. Can someone please help with this?

```
TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
------------------------------

There was an error trying to establish an Oracle connection with the database server.

------------------------------
```

**Below is all the version information**

**SQL Server Version Info**

```
SQL Server Management Studio 15.0.18410.0
SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) 16.100.47008.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools 15.0.19750.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 10.0.17763.1
Microsoft MSXML 3.0 6.0
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0.30319.42000
Operating System 10.0.17763
Oracle Client version installed 12
```

**Visual Studio Version Info**

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 (2)
Version 16.11.15


Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer
Version 15.0.2000.123
```

**Connectors installed**

```
Attunity connector v5 installed but not visible in the SSIS toolbox

Microsoft Connector for Oracle v1 Installed and visible
```

Answer (score 1):

I have specified the Oracle Home path in the connector properties below. Add path to both OracleHome and OracleHome64 and is has started to pick the correct Oracle Home.

[image]

Another resolution suggested below did work as well. I didnt even need to use the Oracle Client. Updating the tnsname with the below format working smoothly in VS2019 and VS2017.

```
 [//]host[:port][/service_name]
```

Comment: If you are using **Microsoft Connector for Oracle v1** it comes with its own ODBC driver. So, there is no need to install and use Oracle Client.

Comment: Thankyou so much. Do you know if attunity connector works with VS2017?

Comment: Yes,  Attunity Oracle connector is working with VS2017

Comment: Thankyou so much. I was able to make Attunity work with VS2017. And I was able to make the connection work without the client too. I'll update my answer and add the details. By any chance, have you used attunity with any of the new version of VS? VS2019 or VS2022??